# magento 2 any type of emails is not working

Tags: magento2, email

when user purchases an item, email is not going neither to the client nor to the admin. what should i do to make the emails working?

Answer (score 2):

Install below extension and add required configuration details in admin.

```
https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this extension.You can send emails after configuring it.
https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-custom-smtp

Comment: this is sending only test mail

Answer (score 0):

For email send you have to configure SMTP first.

You can purchase SMTP free extension for Magento 2 from below link and configure as per your settings.

[CUSTOM SMTP - MAGENTO® 2.0](https://store.emizentech.com/magento2/custom-smtp.html)